# PySide & Python3: TypeError on QAction

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

I'm puzzled. I run PySide with Python3 under Ubuntu 13.10.
I can't get past a simple task where my testing suite gave an error; I narrowed down the problem to a two-liner:

```
from PySide.QtGui import QAction
a = QAction("Test")
```

This is it. If I just run these two lines directly in the /usr/bin/python3 interpreter (v3.3.2), it shouts at me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QAction' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QAction(str)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QAction(PySide.QtCore.QObject)
  PySide.QtGui.QAction(PySide.QtGui.QIcon, unicode, PySide.QtCore.QObject)
  PySide.QtGui.QAction(unicode, PySide.QtCore.QObject)
```

I don't really know what this should mean. I thought ALL (str) strings in Python3 are unicode. Qhy does PySide complain about not being implicitely the same type (str <=> unicode)?

Any help welcome, I am lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG, I did it again. 1min after posting to stackoverflow, i got the solution, after hours of frustrating work earlier ;-)

Solution is simple: it has nothing to do with the str - unicode conversion. QAction at least needs a text argument (str, bytes, unicode...) AND a parent (a QObject derivate) - I forgot this, just **None** is enough.